# What is the tense of this word and why?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

The sentence:

> You see, I have dumped my iPhone and bought myself an old-style, internet-free dumb phone (or “feature phone”, as the new branding would call it).

1. What is the tense of the word "bought"? Is it Present Perfect or Past Simple?
2. If it is Past Simple then why is the "dumped in Present Perfect and the "bought" in Past Simple? Is it ONLY because it's assumed that the purchase of the new phone was conducted AFTER the old one was dumped (which is not necessarily the case)? And had the timing of these actions been unknown then the Present Perfect would have been used for those two verbs?

Comment: It's possible to find present perfect followed by simple past, especially in less formal contexts where it's common to switch tenses, or where the two verbs refer to different situations/times/frequencies. But I agree the most likely and logical explanation is that both are present perfect.

Comment: It's in Present Perfect. If you wanted it to be in Past Simple, you would have had to write *I have dumped my iPhone and I bought myself an old-style, internet-free dumb phone.* (And this sentence sounds somewhat awkward, because there's no reason to put *dumped* and *bought* in two different tenses.)

Comment: The auxiliary **have** forming the present perfect  is understood to carry forward to subsequent verbs.  *I've made my bed and (have) tidied the room.*   When there is a simple past it comes first:  *We bought the house and have fixed it up.*   This is not quite grammatical: "I've been there and saw it."

Comment: I say "not quite" because we *can* carry the subject "I" forward to the second verb, and in that case it's like two separate "sentences" connected by "and": *I've been there -- and (I) saw it.* In that case, the two verb phrases are uncorrelated. The second clause is not integral with the first, or quasi-integral.

Comment: Thank you guys! I think I should consider that this word is in Present Perfect and I might have confused the Present Perfect with the Past Perfect when suggested that those two actions (dumping and buying) could be consecutive. Funny enough: GPT-4 also thought that the word "bought" was in Past Simple.

Comment: Did your sentence come from this place? https://tr-ex.me/%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87/brand+new+phone#gref

Comment: No. *Bought* is Present Simple, but here we have what amounts to *have (dumped and bought)*.